# Regular expression to exclude specific characters and words C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to build a Regex in C# to match all words/digits/characters except these:

- `&`
- `,`
- `and` (as a single word)
- `AND` (as a single word)
- `And` (as a single word)

The following expression works perfectly to exclude the first two characters (`&` and `,`):

```
@"^[^&,]+$"
```

I was trying something like the following expression to exclude the words (and, AND, And) but wasn't able to make it work neither separately from characters nor together:

```
"\b(?!and|AND|And\b)w+"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: If this should be separate "words" then `(?<!\S)(?!and|AND|And)[^\s&,]+(?!\S)` See https://regex101.com/r/p4azwn/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anchor your pattern, move the boundary into the lookahead, and then replace `w+` with the one to exclude `,` and `&`:

```
var pattern = @"^(?!.*\b(and|And|AND)\b)[^&,]+$";
```

The `.*` in front of the `\b(and|And|AND)\b` part of the lookadhead ensures that the engine attempts to exhaust the whole input string to satisfy the assertion instead of just looking at the start of the input.

Comment: @Alyona You're welcome. Beware that this (assertions inside anchored variable-length assertions) may have terrible performance characteristics on long input strings - if at all possible you might want to just split it into 2 separate search operations

Comment: I understand, thank you for letting me know! I'm using it for a short string for now, so I think the original solution will work:)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a negative lookahead assertion in your regular expression. Here's a regex pattern that should match all words, digits, and characters except for "&," and the words "and," "AND," and "And" as whole words:

```cs
string input = "Your input string here";
string pattern = @"(?i)\b(?![&,]|and)\w+\b";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Explanation:

- `(?i)` at the beginning makes the regex case-insensitive.
- `\b` asserts a word boundary.
- `(?![&,]|and)` is a negative lookahead assertion. It ensures that what follows is not "&," or the word "and" in any case.
- `\w+` matches one or more word characters.
- The final `\b` asserts another word boundary to ensure we match whole words.

This regex pattern should successfully match words, digits, and characters while excluding the specified characters and words.

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough response Paul! I tried using the pattern suggested in my Model, but for some reason it didn't seem to catch the invalid characters/words. The answer suggested by Mathias above worked for me, so I will go with that pattern for now. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @Alyona You're very welcome! I'm glad you found a solution that works for your needs. If you ever have more questions or run into any other issues, don't hesitate to reach out. Wishing you success with your project!